# Ограничение на количество открытых одинаковых окон

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

По нажатию на кнопку открывается окно "Настройки". Но сколько я раз нажму на кнопку, столько этих окон и открывается. Как создать условие, что только одно окно "Настройки" может быть активным.
`setModal` не хочется. При проверке на `isVisible` ничего не меняется.

```
void MainWindow::on_SettingsButton_clicked()
{
    SettingsWindow = new settings();
    SettingsWindow->exec();
}
```

Comment: Я полагаю  то это не QDialog? exec() показывает его как модальный

Comment: Как раз таки QDialog.  Но насколько я понимаю exec не должен срабатывать на QDialog? Думаю ввести булеву переменную и просто по ней if сделать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы создаете новый QWidget каждый раз. Он не разрушается, если не разрушится владелец.

```
SettingsWindow = new settings();
```

Сдесь не задан владелец, скорее всего д.б. `this`. Если же диалг должен "болтаться"  вокруг да около, то проще всего - хранить инфорамицю о том , что он создан или нет где-то еще. Можно это делать по разному.

```
void MainWindow::on_SettingsButton_clicked()
{
    showSettings();
}   

void MainWindow::showSettings(bool  flag = true)
{
    static QAtomicInt created = false;

    if (created.testAndSet(false,true)) {
       SettingsWindow = new settings();
       SettingsWindow->exec();
    }
    else
       SettingsWindow->someItialization();

    SettingsWindow->show(flag);

}
```

Comment: Получилось, но немного не так, как я хочу. Но я не понимаю почему. Это QDialog, указал родителя(как и написано - this) и после этого оно стало модальным. А мне хотелось бы, чтобы его можно было свернуть и пользоваться родительским окном.

Comment: да, когда у него нет родителя, он немодальный. т.к. модальность у него относительная. В этом случае надо хранить состояние. Объект не уничтожается после закрытия.

Comment: @Mussorable поэспериментируй с моим примером

Comment: Спасибо, но вот так и не хотелось делать. Я только начал изучать qt, вот думал есть функция проверки на этот счет. Да модальным оставлю, в принципе не критично. В будущем, наверно, найду по ситуации выход

Comment: @Mussorable в таком слуяае, почему не создать диалог в конструкторе окна? Один раз. а дальше только вызывать

Answer (score 0):

Замените

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Другой путь, если окно не должно быть модальным:

```
//form.h
#include <QWidget>

namespace Ui {
class Form;
}

class Form : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Form(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~Form();

private:
    Ui::Form *ui;

    static int counter;
};

//form.cpp
#include "form.h"
#include "ui_form.h"

Form::Form(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Form)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
    ++counter;

    if(counter > 1)
    {
        counter--;
        close();
    }

    show();
}

Form::~Form()
{
    delete ui;
}

int Form::counter = 0;
```

Еще есть паттерн проектирования Singltone:

```
// Singleton.h
class Singleton
{
  private:
    static Singleton * p_instance;
    // Конструкторы и оператор присваивания недоступны клиентам
    Singleton() {}
    Singleton( const Singleton& );  
    Singleton& operator=( Singleton& );
  public:
    static Singleton * getInstance() {
        if(!p_instance)           
            p_instance = new Singleton();
        return p_instance;
    }
};
// Singleton.cpp
#include "Singleton.h"

Singleton* Singleton::p_instance = 0;
```